# How to find similar messages in a larggest database

Tags: php, mysql, artificial-intelligence

I have a database with 2.000.000 messages. When an user receipt a message I need find relevant messages in my database based in occurrence of words.

I had tried run a batch process to summarize my database:
1 - Store all words(except an, a, the, of, for...) of all messages.
2 - Create association between all messages and the words contained therein (I also store the frequence of this word appears in the message.)

Then, when I receipt a message:
1 - I parse words (it looks like with the first step of my batch process.)
2 - Perform query in database to fetching messages sorted by numbers of coincident words.

However, the process of updating my words base and the query to fetching similar messages are very heavy and slow. The word base update lasts ~1.2111 seconds for a message of 3000 bytes. The query similar messages lasts ~9.8 seconds for a message with same size.

The database tuning already been done and the code works fine.

I need a better algorithm to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you just need a full-text search? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I would highly recommend the book "Collective Intelligence": http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Collective-Intelligence-Building-Applications/dp/0596529325/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1296849440&sr=8-1 . It's written for Python, but there is plenty of theory for you to implement it in another language. The very first chapter of the book involves what you are trying to do

Comment: I just made the order, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using setting up Apache Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). It is very easy to setup and index millions of documents. Solr handles all the optimization necessary (although it is open source so you can tweak it if you feel you need to).

You can then query using available APIs, I prefer the Java API SolrJ (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj). I typically see results returned in under one second.

Solr typically outperforms MySQL for text indexing.

Comment: I'll perform a test an implementation using Apache Solr

Answer (score 1):

Similarity Matchings is still a particularly complicated field, but you might take a look at [full text matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) in the MySQL Reference, particularly some of the more complex examples.

It should be possible for you to run a one-off job to build a similarity matrix for all your current messages, then just run a nightly batch to add new messages to the similarity matrix.

Comment: I was made a nightly batch to update similarity matriz. And I'll perform a benchmark of an implementation using full text search. thanks